# Не найдено свойства deserialize при работе с react-yandex-maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, яндекс-карты

Я пытаюсь создать метку в `<YMaps>` через `react-yandex-maps`. Я использую [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Menu from '../components/Menu'
import {YMaps, Map, Placemark} from 'react-yandex-maps'

const mapState = {center: [43.196035, 76.893945], zoom: 16};

const MyPlacemark = () => (
  <YMaps>
    <Map state={mapState}>    
      <Placemark
        geometry={{
          coordinates: [55.751574, 37.573856]
        }}
        properties={{
          hintContent: 'Собственный значок метки',
          balloonContent: 'Это красивая метка'
        }}
        options={{
          iconImageSize: [30, 42],
          iconImageOffset: [-3, -42]
        }}
      />    
    </Map>
  </YMaps>
);

class yandex extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu />
        <h1>Yandex</h1>
        <MyPlacemark />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default yandex;
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Cannot read property 'deserialize' of undefined

В чём проблема?

Comment: Приведите минимальный пример кода на https://jsfiddle.net, иллюстрирующий проблему

Answer (score 0):

Возможно примеры для старой версии - на 2.2.0 работает

> For the previous stable version see v2.2.0